# In C#, Why Is A Stack of Structs Referencing Reference Types Slower to Push Than Structs Containing Value Types?

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection, boxing

If I have a Stack, I would have expected that a mystack.Push() would be about the same performance for T being a struct, and maybe a little slower for T being a reference type. When I benchmark this scenario, it seems that a struct containing a reference type performs slightly worse than a struct containing a value. This despite both structs being the same size in memory (64 bits).

The benchmark was performed using .NET 6 and benchmarkdotnet.

Here are my test structs; note they should all be the same size on my x64 processor:

```
public readonly record struct RecStruct(long A);

public readonly record struct PtrStruct(UIntPtr A);

public readonly record struct StructRef(object Ref);
```

And here is my benchmarkdotnet project class

```
public class StructPerformance
{
    private const int repeats = 1_000_000;

    [Benchmark]
    public Stack<RecStruct> PushStructWithCap()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<RecStruct>(repeats);
        var strct = new RecStruct(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
        {
            stack.Push(strct);
        }
        return stack;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Stack<PtrStruct> PushPtrStructWithCap()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<PtrStruct>(repeats);
        var ptr = new UIntPtr(0);
        var strct = new PtrStruct(ptr);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
        {
            stack.Push(strct);
        }
        return stack;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Stack<StructRef> PushStructRefWithCap()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<StructRef>(repeats);
        var obj = new object();
        var strct = new StructRef(obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
        {
            stack.Push(strct);
        }
        return stack;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Stack<object> PushObjectWithCap()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<object>(repeats);
        var obj = new object();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
        {
            stack.Push(obj);
        }
        return stack;
    }
}
```

My benchmark results are interesting, and seem to show that pushing a struct containing an object reference performs about as poorly as pushing an object, while an unmanaged structs perform better.

```
| Method                | Mean     | Error     | StdDev    | Median   |
|---------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|
| PushStructWithCap    | 2.605 ms | 0.0517 ms | 0.1315 ms | 2.583 ms |
| PushPtrStructWithCap | 2.586 ms | 0.0516 ms | 0.1121 ms | 2.558 ms |
| PushStructRefWithCap | 3.245 ms | 0.0643 ms | 0.1207 ms | 3.234 ms |
| PushObjectWithCap    | 3.231 ms | 0.0630 ms | 0.1018 ms | 3.217 ms |
```

What is the reason for the extra ~ns/op on Stack.Push() for structs containing references?

Comment: Perhaps the heap memory allocation of the new object causes the additional overhead. You could add the MemoryDiagnoser just for some extra stats.

Comment: I'd guess the extra GC tracking of the reference on the stack/registers is causing overhead. I doubt any of that overhead is significant in a real app.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I believe you are correct. After thinking about it some more, this is the only possible explanation. It's kind of neat to see the impact of GC in test. If you put your comment in an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: It could be due to GC write barriers. Managed object writes are slightly slower compared to primitives because they all go through a special function that does some bookkeeping for the GC card tables.